# SQL Select statement suddenly retrieving wrong value only when selecting form another query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a order creation form in an Access database where the user selects a product and VBA code is triggered with SQL select statement to retrieve the current availability of that product. This is how it's set up:

1. I have a Packages table where products batches are added to inventory.
2. I have an OrderDetail table where items from product batches are allocated to orders.
3. I have a InventoryPrep query with a the total packaged per batch and field that sums the number of allocated products per batch from the OrderDetail table.
4. Then I have an Inventory query that that has a calculated field that takes the TotalPackaged field from the InventoryPrep query and subtracts the TotalAllocated field from the InventoryPrep query.

Here is the VBA code in my form, triggered by an update to the [Batch] combo box:

```vb
Dim VBatch As String
VBatch = Me.Batch.Value
Dim VAvail As Double
Dim mySQL As String
Dim conn1 As ADODB.Connection
Set conn1 = CurrentProject.Connection
Dim rs1 As New ADODB.Recordset
rs1.ActiveConnection = conn1

mySQL = "SELECT Available FROM Inventory WHERE BatchID = " & "'" & VBatch & "'"
        rs1.Open mySQL
        rs1.MoveFirst
        VAvail = rs1.Fields("Available").Value
        Forms!ChangeOrders.ChangeOrderSubform.Form.Availability.Value = VAvail
        rs1.Close
        conn1.Close
        Set rs1 = Nothing
        Set conn1 = Nothing
```

This has been working just fine for weeks, retreiving the correct available amount as packaged items are added to the Packages table and orders are being added in the OrderDetail table. Yesterday it started returning the Packaged field from the InventoryPrep query instead.

I tried a bunch of things and then created a table from the query and used the SELECT statement to look it up in the table. That worked. There is something about my query set up that has caused it to stop recognizing my calculated field. I need help!

This is my first time posting and I hope this is enough information. I'm pretty new to Access and VBA but I've learned a lot from reading in this forum. I hope someone can help or let me know what other information could shed light on the problem.

Comment: What information should I provide? This is my first post. I can usually figure things out by troubleshooting or reading others' questions. I'm lost on this one.

Comment: I rewrote the question. Hopefully more clear.

Comment: What is the value of VBatch? If you set a break point and copy the exact sql query produced are you saying it returns something from other than the Inventory table?

Comment: Also I don't know much about VBA but this is prone to sql injection. If VBatch is taking user input they could easily do what they will to your DB

Comment: Vbatch is whatever batch they select in a drop down in the form. And yes, the value that SQL pulls from the query is different than the value SQL pulls from the table created from the query. 

Right now my query is a separate Access object but perhaps I should try running it in code within this sub.

Comment: I'm curious why you select field `Available` in `mySQL`, but able to get the value from field `FlowerAvailable`.  Is that all of your code?  Beside, will the query return more than 1 rows?

Comment: No, I was just trying to simplify my naming conventions for the example but it's the same (edited my code above). Put the query returns only one row. I can look at my query outside of the form and see the value of the Available field for that batch and it's one thing but returns something else with the SQL select in the form.

Answer (score 1):

To read a single value from a table or query, your code is a bit over the top.

For this scenario, Access has the [`DLookup` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937).

```vb
VAvail = DLookup("Available", "Inventory", "BatchID = '" & VBatch & "'")
Forms!ChangeOrders.ChangeOrderSubform.Form.Availability.Value = VAvail
```

That's all that is needed.

Comment: Wow I didn't realize I could this. Thank you so much!